# google charts timeline - cannot read property length of null

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Following there are 2 examples of google charts code. The only difference in the last example is the start second. Does anybody know, why I get "cannot read property 'length' of null" in the last example? Also if I shorten the name of row 2 and 3 from "Second Test entry number 2" to a shorter, the chart is displayed.

Working: https://jsfiddle.net/5rotomyc/

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Role' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

         dataTable.addRows([
['First', null, new Date(2017,1,15, 22, 40, 27), new Date(2017,10,29, 23, 59, 59)],
['Second Test entry number 2', null, new Date(2017,8,4, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2018,0,16, 23, 59, 59)],
['Second Test entry number 2', null, new Date(2018,0,25, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2018,1,06, 23, 59, 59)]
]);


        chart.draw(dataTable);
      }
```

Second example which is not working https://jsfiddle.net/ypz095g9/:

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Role' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

         dataTable.addRows([
['First', null, new Date(2017,1,15, 22, 40, 26), new Date(2017,10,29, 23, 59, 59)],
['Second Test entry number 2', null, new Date(2017,8,4, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2018,0,16, 23, 59, 59)],
['Second Test entry number 2', null, new Date(2018,0,25, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2018,1,06, 23, 59, 59)]
]);


        chart.draw(dataTable);
      }
```

I'm getting desperate right here. hope somebody can help with this bug. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that the names, the first parameter in each row is supposed to be unique, and by changing the name of the 2nd one to something else you restore the uniqueness? I notice the last two rows have the same name.

Comment: hi n8wrl. the names don't need to be unique. by default google charts is grouping rows with the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like a problem with `addRows`

seen weird stuff happen when an entire column only has `null` values
(the code actually works for me *as-is* in chrome)

the `'Role'` column is optional, you can remove it...
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

     dataTable.addRows([
['First', new Date(2017,1,15, 22, 40, 26), new Date(2017,10,29, 23, 59, 59)],
['Second Test entry number 2', new Date(2017,8,4, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2018,0,16, 23, 59, 59)],
['Second Test entry number 2', new Date(2018,0,25, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2018,1,06, 23, 59, 59)]
]);


    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

---

or use a blank string `''` instead...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Role' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

     dataTable.addRows([
['First', '', new Date(2017,1,15, 22, 40, 26), new Date(2017,10,29, 23, 59, 59)],
['Second Test entry number 2', '', new Date(2017,8,4, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2018,0,16, 23, 59, 59)],
['Second Test entry number 2', '', new Date(2018,0,25, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2018,1,06, 23, 59, 59)]
]);


    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: oh yes. this really helped. I have no idea, why null seems to be the problem in some situations but not in all.... but anyway. thank you very much.

Comment: I'd followed the guide at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#customizing-tooltips, having the second column = null. Following your suggestion, I changed it to an empty string and the error resolved! Thanks for saving my sanity.